# MYSQL Where statement/clause being ignored

Tags: mysql, where-clause

```
SELECT country.continent, country.name, city.district, city.name, city.population
FROM world.country, world.city
WHERE city.population < 3000000 
LIMIT 20, 30;
```

I'm getting a cartesian product instead of a table showing the contents of the select clause where the city population is over 3 million.

world is the name of the database
country and city are tables

please help.

Comment: You need to join the two tables explicitly rather than the way you're doing it. Can you tell us more about the structure of your tables?

Comment: Since im not quite sure how to efficently describe the structure.
This database is very huge.

This is the metadata http://imgur.com/VXyDinf

This is the diagram http://imgur.com/1vkJW7y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the tables together:

```
SELECT country.continent, country.name, city.district, city.name, city.population
FROM world.country JOIN
     world.city
     ON country.code = city.countrycode
WHERE city.population < 3000000 
LIMIT 20, 30;
```

As a hint for writing SQL:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit joins.  These are more powerful than implicit joins (and many people think they make queries easier to read and maintain).

Comment: I just entered the code in and it still seems to ignore my WHERE statement and why did you use ON on country.code instead of on one of the things being selected?

Comment: @felipe343 - because `country.code` is the primary key.

Comment: Oh jeez...I put the equality symbol. Sorry and thanks